# How to map an action in grails 3 to "/"?

Tags: grails, grails3

I'm using Grails 3.3.10 and trying to map "/" to a controller action, where the user is redirected after a successful login.

In UrlMappings I have:

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {

      "/"(controller:'app')
   ...
...
```

When the user signs in, the app is redirected to the root http://localhost:8090/, but it shows a generated view from Grails:

```
Welcome to Grails

Congratulations, you have successfully started your first Grails
application! At the moment this is the default page, feel free to
modify it to either redirect to a controller or display whatever
content you may choose. Below is a list of controllers that are
currently deployed in this application, click on each to execute
its default action:

Available Controllers:

....
```

I deleted the default index.gsp and the main.gsp layout, but that view with the controllers is still appearing and I can't get my action to be executed.

If I remove the UrlMapping "/"(controller:'app'), the action is executed OK and the view is the correct one, but the URL is http://localhost:8090/app/index

Is it possible to display the view from app/index being the URL mapped to "/"?

Comment: Did you remove the default mapping which maps `"/"` with `"/"(view:"/index")`?

Comment: It is very odd that even after deleting the files they are being rendered.  There is some other piece of the puzzle that isn't mentioned in the question I expect.

Comment: Look for plugins contributing items that are getting in the way.  If you can share a project which demonstrates the behavior, it would be more simple to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown I think the view is scaffold autogenerated view that lists the controllers in my app. I think it might be some plugin since my code looks pretty much the same es your sample project. Thanks!

Comment: "I think the view is scaffold autogenerated view that lists the controllers in my app." - I don't think the scaffolding plugin contributes anything like that.

Comment: the issue was in a plugin having the default urlmappings there, removed the file and it worked on the main project

Comment: I am glad that you were able to chase it down.  Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to display the view from app/index being the URL mapped
>   to "/"?

Yes it is.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosurlmapping.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosurlmapping/blob/452980ca99bbd5ccc217047534798001a8d7d9cb/grails-app/controllers/pablopazosurlmapping/UrlMappings.groovy

```
package pablopazosurlmapping

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:'app')
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosurlmapping/blob/452980ca99bbd5ccc217047534798001a8d7d9cb/grails-app/controllers/pablopazosurlmapping/AppController.groovy

```
package pablopazosurlmapping

class AppController {
    def index() {
        [name: 'Pablo']
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosurlmapping/blob/452980ca99bbd5ccc217047534798001a8d7d9cb/grails-app/views/app/index.gsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>${name} Was Here!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, your project works perfeclty, though I have the same url mapping and controller in my project, the controller action is not being executed and I get an autogenerated view that lists the controllers in my project. I guess I need to create a project from scratch and copy my classes to make it work.

Comment: @PabloPazos It is hard to say why your app is behaving the way it is without seeing it. You could have a plugin contributing url mappings or interceptors affecting requests or any number of things that would be difficult to guess without seeing the project.  Best of luck!

Comment: it seems there was a bug in 3.3.10 with the urlmappings from plugins messing the urlmappings from the app, I guess I'll also update to 3.3.11 https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11335